# Symfony CollectionList

Tags: php, symfony

I have:

```
    ->add('skills', CollectionType::class, array(
        'entry_type' => TagType::class,
        'allow_add'  => true,
        'allow_delete' => true,
    ))
```

In the form builder with TagType being

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('id', IntegerType::class);
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Tag',
    ));
}
```

What I am trying to do is to post just the tag ID's in the form but render the form with fetched names for those tags. I have attempted to:

```
if($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
{
  $form_arr = $request->request->get('form');
  $skills = (array_key_exists('skills', $form_arr)) ? $form_arr['skills'] : array();
  foreach($skills as $key => $role) { $skills[$key] = $role['id']; }
  if(count($skills) > 0)
  {
    $em->clear();
    $roles = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Tag')->findById($skills);
    $project->setSkills($roles);
  }
}
```

but as soon as we reach `$form->handleRequest($request);` the whole form is rendered absent names for tags.

Answer (score 2):

Symfony already provides you a solution for these cases. It's called data transformers.

There is an example similar to what you're trying to do.

http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#creating-a-reusable-issue-selector-field

I recommend you to read the whole article from the beginning.

Comment: @nakashu I don't recommend just grabbing a code example and using it.

The link I gave have lots of explaining and if you want to understand what you're doing you have to read it :)

Comment: @Moein You do not necessarily need a code example, but it would be nice if you could paraphrase the answer (given in the link). So your answer here will still be valid and useful for visitors, even if the link is broken (for whatever reason)